# MySQL -- insert a VARCHAR value from T1 into a DECIMAL field in T2

Tags: php, mysql, types, decimal, varchar

In Table_1, I have imported data from a spreadsheet.  In one table column there are mixed values: 94.7, 45.0, 36, car, bus....etc.  The datatype is VARCHAR(10)

I want to insert the values from this column from Table_1 into a DECIMAL(5,1) field in Table_2.  I want the non-numeric values to register as 0.0.  This is important.

I've tried several things, including CAST(), which works in my MySQL GUI, but gives a long series of warnings.  Here is an example of the type of SQL I have tried.

```
DELETE FROM table_2;
INSERT INTO table_2 (NAME, decimal_column)
   (SELECT NAME
         , CAST(varchar_column AS DECIMAL(5,1))
      FROM table_1) ;
```

Example of MySQL warnings.

> Warning Code : 1366 Incorrect decimal
>   value: '' for column '' at row -1
>
> Warning Code : 1292 Truncated
>   incorrect DECIMAL value: 'house'

Also, PHP will have none of it.  When I try to run the same query using PHP, I get this fatal error message:

> Incorrect decimal value: '' for column
>   '' at row -1

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're clearing `table_2` you can use `TRUNCATE table_2;` which may be faster.

One way to do this (though I don't know if it's the best; it may be a bit slow for large datasets) is to use a regular expression:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (NAME, decimal_column)
(SELECT NAME
     , IF(varchar_column REGEXP '^[[:digit:].]+$', varchar_column, 0.0)
  FROM table_1) ;
```

This is assuming there's no whitespace in the decimal values of `varchar_column`. If there might be then you can use `TRIM` as follows:

```
IF(TRIM(varchar_column) REGEXP '^[[:digit:].]+$', TRIM(varchar_column), 0.0)
```

Comment: Yes, mjec, this did the trick.  No MySQL warning messages at all!  Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting for posterity that this may raise errors if the column contains values like `'2.2.2'` in which case the `REGEXP` would need to be written. But glad it's worked for you @dave!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the following and it worked great for me:

```
INSERT INTO `table_2` (`decimal_column`) SELECT CAST(`varchar_column` AS DECIMAL(5,1)) FROM `table_1`;
```

The table I used had a blank value, a decimal value (as a VARCHAR) and the word "house" and everything converted as expected.

The warnings can be ignored.  It's essentially MySQL telling you that it tried to convert data that it couldn't convert. The word "house" for example can't be converted into a decimal value so MySQL is warning you (and so is PHP.)  The reason why you're not seeing the error in the MySQL GUI is because the error is suppressed because the query worked.

If you want to hide the errors, you can always add an @ symbol in front of the PHP call (i.e. @mysqli->query('...'), use ini_set('display_errors', false) to disable all of the errors, or error_reporting(E_NONE).

Comment: Thank you, Francois.  I had tried this, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do away with the MySQL warning messages.

Comment: If you want to remove the messages, try the @ in front of the call. It's the best way to remove the error message for that call only. If you want it for all of that PHP script, use the ini_set('display_errors', false) or error_reporting(E_NONE) options.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work, given that the mysql client is throwing the error back to PHP (PHP is executing a single statement).

Comment: MySQL is not actually throw errors, just warnings. It'll work just fine. I've actually tested it for you! :)